# C# Montouch/Xamarin - Camera Shutter Speed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is it possible to control the shutter speed in iOS6?

I'm using C# Monotouch/Xamarin to build my application.

Thanks.

Comment: According to [this question][1], there is no public API to control shutter speed.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed), Apple does not provide any public API to control shutter speed.

You could try binding the private APIs mentioned to allow them to be accessed from Xamarin.iOS, but that would cause your app to be rejected by the App Store review process.