# iPhone set image resolution on camera programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera

I want to set the iphone camera max resolution to 5 Mega pixel. I have already written code to resize after taking the photo - but it applies a lot of memory pressure. So wanted to know if there is any way to set it directly on the camera programmatically.

Comment: AFAIK there are various preset options for camera quality. You can't set the resolution to be a specific value though.

Comment: Thanks Fogmeister. The preset value does not have the target resolution I am seeking... SO I guess I am out of luck here.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I think you have options for 640x480, 720, 1080, low, medium, high and full. (Or something like that) That's all you can do in the actual camera capture session.

Comment: please! read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed) may help you