# How to use RunTime Header methods in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I want to control the shutter speed of the `AVCaptureDevice`.By doing search on google I found 
this [change shutter speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed)  and came to know that there are runtime headers methods for `AVCaptureDevice` that are not available under the developer.apple.So found that we can use these methods:
1.Using `O-tool` -But seems this is outdated or stopped by Apple.
2.`Class -dump`.
The second one `class-dump`.I tried to use but not successful.I have downloaded the class-dump
file and use the terminal command line but cannot replace the class file.It says that it requires Executable file.But the file that I have to replace is just a header file.

```
/Users/gaurav.garg/Desktop/DumpFramework/class-dump -H /Users/gaurav.garg/Downloads/iOS-Runtime-Headers-master/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework -o /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/
```

like :

```
class-dump -H Source(runtime header file location) -O (Destination i.e system framework location)
```

this gives:

> class-dump: Input file
>   (/Users/gaurav.garg/Downloads/iOS-Runtime-Headers-master/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework)
>   doesn't contain an executable.

**So basically How can I use this runtime header methods in xcode via Class-Dump or any other way ?**
And this is an internal app **not for App Store.**

EDIT : After running this command in terminal:

```
/Users/gaurav.garg/Desktop/DumpFramework/class-dump -H /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation -o /Users/gaurav.garg/Desktop
```

Now I have successfully dumped a bunch of  AVFoundation .h files into desktop.That are dumped from AVFoundation Executable file via Class-Dump.So How can I use these all .h files(Some methods in device.h file) into Xcode.Because I have already added AVFoundation Framwework that contains the standard .h files.Thanks In Advance.

Comment: The reason that they don't appear in Apple's documentation is because they are **private** methods. Use of private methods is a guaranteed rejection from the app store.

Comment: This is not for app Store and only for internal use.

Comment: you have your source and destination mixed up. notice how it complains about input from your users folder instead of the SDK framework.

Comment: But after changing the source to /Users/gaurav.garg/Desktop/DumpFramework/class-dump -H /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation -o /Users/gaurav.garg/Desktop
class-dump: Input file (/Applications/Xcode) does not exist.